How to fix this typing issue with Legend State, React Native, and Typescript
I am having an issue including my Legend state within my React Context in Typescript. Legend version (@legendapp/state) is 3.0.0-alpha.38, React version is 18.2.0, and Typescript version is 5.3.3. My setup is:
type Store = {
  stuff: string;
}


export type StevenContextType = {
  store: Observable<Store>;
};

const store$ = useObservable({
  stuff: "yo"
});

export const StevenContext = React.createContext<StevenContextType | null>(null);

<StevenContext.Provider value={{ store$ }}>

And the error message I'm getting is: Type {store$: ObservableObjectFunctions<ObservableProps<{stuff: string}> & NonObservableProps<{stuff: string}>> & ObservableChildren<ObservableProps<{stuff: string}>> & ObservableFunctionChildren<NonObservableProps<{stuff: string}>>} is not assignable to type StevenContextType | null 
Any help would be deeply appreciated; I am sure there is a typing nuance that I'm just not grasping, but I cannot figure it out.

AFAICT this appears to be a simple typo: your context provider component expects a value type with a store property (not store$) — so value={{ store: store$ }}. However, the question lacks a [mre], so I can't be sure. Does that solve the problem?

in ts const store$ = useObservable({ stuff: "yo" });
Instead of useObservable hook, use observable to create the store. This is the correct function from the Legend library to create an observable object

It seems your issue is from the typing of the store$ objects returned by your useObservable hook. There is a high chance that what your StevenContext is expecting is not being returned by your useObservable hook. You can start by making sure the type you're providing to StevenContext is properly described by what the useObservable hook is returning.
type Store = {
  stuff: string;
};

export type StevenContextType = {
  store$: Observable<Store>;
};

const store$ = useObservable<Store>({
  stuff: "yo"
});

export const StevenContext = React.createContext<StevenContextType | null>(null);

<StevenContext.Provider value={{ store$ }}>

if after explicitly typing the observable using the correct return from the useObservable hook and updating the SteveContextType to match the observable object, and you still encounter this issue you might need to check your @legendapp/state for the correct types to use
